# Custom field with Types: get custom field's value label (of type select)

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

We use the [Types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/) plugin to setup different custom products for a client. A certain custom post (product) contains some custom fields which is a drop-down select. When creating a new product of this type, the user may select one option from that list.

For example, let say that certain product has a custom field of type select with the following options set :

```
1 = Option A
2 = Option B
3 = Option C
```

Now, in a template, I'm trying to display the label for that custom field. The best thing I came up with is by doing :

```
$value = reset(get_post_custom_values('custom_field', $post->ID));
```

which would return a string, for example `"1"`, the value of the custom field. Now, this is worthless as I need to display the label (the chosen item from the list, for example `"Option A"`) in that template.

How do I find the associated label for that custom field value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know, and after much code sniffing, I finally have a working solution :

First, the custom field may start with `wpcf-` (for example: `wpcf-custom-field`). This prefix may be ignored and only the remaining characters kept. As in

```
$customField = substr($fieldName, 5);  // $fieldName = 'wpcf-custom-field';
```

Now, the custom field data may be fetch via the function `wpcf_admin_fields_get_field` which is located in the **Types** plugin directory under `includes/fields.php`. For example :

```
$fieldConfig = wpcf_admin_fields_get_field($customField);
```

Among other things, the options may be collected with this code :

```
$fieldOptions = array();
if (isset($fieldConfig['data']['options'])) {
   foreach ($fieldConfig['data']['options'] as $option) {
      $fieldOptions[$option['title']] = $option['value'];
   }
}
```

Which, if the custom field is a type select, will return an array like

```
array(
   '1' => 'Option A',
   '2' => 'Option B',
   '3' => 'Option C'
);
```